# how to select value of a column that matches the max function result in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table having certain data related to a user's test taken. i wanted to get the max(testnumber) from the table given below along with the status corresponds to the max(testnumber).

[image: images shows the table studentchaptertest. and shows the test attented by student.i want o/p max(testnumber)=3 and its status ;1 as o/p]

```
SELECT @LastAttemptedTest=MAX([TestNumber] FROM [dbo].[StudentChapterwiseTest] WHERE 
    [ChapterId]=584 AND [StudentId]=212045 

SELECT Status FROM [dbo].[StudentChapterwiseTest] WHERE [TestNumber]=@LastAttemptedTest AND
    [ChapterId]=584 AND [StudentId]=212045
```

i am trying to get  is max(testnumber) and status correspond to the result of max(testnumber) in a single select query

Comment: select status, id from  test_table where id=(select id from test_table order by id desc limit 1)

Comment: Post your sample data as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by studentid order by testnumber desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

**EDIT :** If you want one row then use `top (1)` clause :

```
select top (1) t.*
from table t
order by t.testnumber desc;
```

Comment: @Aravind. . . How this doesn't solve your problem ?

Comment: its results multiple raw i just wanted single raw as result. i hope row_number() is not required. i am beginner,so pardon if i am wrong on this

Answer (score 0):

Select max test number in a sub-query and JOIN on that

```
SELECT t.status, t.testNumber
FROM StudentChapterwiseTest t
JOIN (SELECT StudentId, ChapterId, MAX(status) as max_stat 
      FROM StudentChapterwiseTest
      GROUP BY StudentId, ChapterId) mt ON t.status = mt.max_stat  AND t.chapterId = mt.chapterid AND t.studentId = mt.studentid
WHERE [ChapterId]=584 AND [StudentId]=212045
```

Comment: I made a try.This too works for me. Thanks                                   
                                                                                            SELECT status,[TestNumber] FROM [StudentChapterwiseTest] WHERE 
 [TestNumber] = (SELECT MAX([TestNumber])FROM [StudentChapterwiseTest] WHERE [ChapterId]=584 AND [StudentId]=212045) 
 AND [ChapterId]=584 AND [StudentId]=212045;

Comment: @Aravind I have changed my query so variables aren't duplicated